# Bash number extraction from different places in STDOUT

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

Here is the output given by speedtest-cli: (personal information redacted with test data)

```
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Testing from ------ (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)...
Selecting best server based on latency...
Hosted by ------- (------, --) [15.00 km]: 50.00 ms
Testing download speed........................................
Download: 60.00 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed..................................................
Upload: 10.00 Mbit/s
```

Where I want the output to be a comma separated line of ping, dl, ul:

```
50.00, 60.00, 10.00
```

I have been working on a solution and have come up with this:

```
speedtest-cli | sed -n "5p;7p;9p" | grep -oE "[[:digit:]]{1,}" | tr '\n' ,
```

Which outputs:

```
15,00,50,00,60,00,10,00,
```

Which is close to what I want. Except that it is including the distance (15.00km) from the 5th line and splitting based on . as well. Is there a better way to do this using awk or something similar?

Comment: With `sed`, extracting the last number following `: ` on any line: `speedtest-cli | sed -n 's/.*: \([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)[^0-9]*/\1/p' | tr '\n', ','`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using awk you can do:

```
speedtest-cli | awk -v ORS=', ' '/^(Hosted|Download|Upload)/{print $(NF-1)}'
50.00, 60.00, 10.00,
```

To use newline instead of trailing `,` use:

```
speedtest-cli | awk -v ORS=', ' '/^(Hosted |Download:)/{print $(NF-1)}
      /^Upload:/{printf "%s%s", $(NF-1), RS}'
50.00, 60.00, 10.00
```

Comment: Very nice. Is NF-1 the last number float in the string? Also, is there an easy way to replace that last , with a \n for appending to a file? Thanks!

Comment: `NF-1` is last minus 1 field. Will update to replace trailing `,` with `\n`

Answer (score 2):

If your `grep` supports PCRE (`-P`), you can do:

```
% grep -Po '^(Hosted|Download|Upload).*:\K [^ ]+' file.txt | tr '\n' ','; echo
 50.00, 60.00, 10.00,
```

So:

```
speedtest-cli | grep -Po '^(Hosted|Download|Upload).*:\K [^ ]+' | tr '\n' ','; echo
```